# What's the Hilbert transform of power function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function $\alpha(f) = f^s$, with $f \in \Re$ and $0 \lt s \lt 1$, and I am looking for its Hilbert Transform
 $$\hat \alpha(f) =  \frac{1}{\pi} \mathrm{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha(t)}{f-t} dt = \frac{1}{\pi} \mathrm{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{t^s}{f-t} dt$$

I am stuck. It seems to involve contour integral around the pole at $f$ from the denominator and the branch points at $0$ and $\infty$ from the numerator.

Comment: From $\int_0^\infty t^s e^{-b t}dt = b^{-s-1} \Gamma(s)$ we find the Fourier transform of $t^s$ is $A y^{-1-s}1_{y > 0 }+B y^{-1-s}1_{y < 0 }$ so the Fourier transform of its Hilbert transform is $i A y^{-1-s}1_{y > 0 }-i B y^{-1-s}1_{y < 0 }$  and we can inverse Fourier transform both term. The result is true only in the sense of distributions.

Comment: How is the integrand defined when $t<0$?

Comment: @StefanLafon, that's also part of my confusion, but I guess I can do whatever analytic extension that makes sense.

Comment: @reuns, is it possible to work this out with contour integral?

Comment: I don't think so. You are aware that your integral/convolution doesn't converge (it does only in the sense of distributions) ? You don't like my approach ? There is a slight difficulty because $y^{-1-s}$ is not $L^1_{loc}$ at $y=0$ so to find the regularization of the distribution we'd need to extend from $s \in (-1,0)$ to $s \in (0,1)$

Comment: @reuns could you let us know how the integrand is defined for negative $t$?

Comment: My solution assumes the function is any branch of $t^s$ that is analytic on $\Bbb{R}^*$, for example it can be $|t|^s$